# Deleting unneeded rows from a table with 2 criteria

Tags: mysql, field, sql-delete, subquery

I have a many-to-many relations table and I need to DELETE the unneeded rows.
The `lastviews` table's structure is:

```
| user (int) | document (int) | time (datetime) |
```

This table logs the last users which viewed the document. (user, document) is unique. I show only the **last 10 views of a document** and until now I deleted the unneeded like this:

```
DELETE FROM `lastviews` WHERE `document` = ? AND `user` NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT `user` FROM `lastviews` WHERE `document` = ? ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10) AS TAB)
```

However, now I need to also show the **last 5** documents a **user** has viewed. This means I can no longer delete rows using the previous query because it might delete information I need (say a user didn't view documents in 5 minutes and the rows are deleted)

To sum up, I need to delete all the records that aren't in the results of these 2 queries:

```
SELECT ... FROM `lastviews` WHERE `document` = ? ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10
```

**and**

```
SELECT * FROM `lastviews` WHERE `user` = ? ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

I need the logic.

Comment: Of course, I can always create a second table with the same structure but that just doesn't feel right.

Comment: This is definitely a case for creating a temp table. :)

Comment: This brings the question how to insert the rows in the temp table without having to do INSERT statement for each `document` and `user` (to get the last 10 or 5 rows). Or at least make the query do the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this question. I didn't find the answer I was looking for but ended doing it another way.
I decided to remove these records that are 2 days old so there won't be any unused rows in the database.

Answer (score 0):

can an OR in your query resolve your issue?

something like this:

```
DELETE FROM `lastviews` WHERE `document` = ? AND (`user` NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT `user` FROM `lastviews` WHERE `document` = ? ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10) AS TAB) OR 'user' NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'user' FROM `lastviews` WHERE `user` = ? ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 0, 5) AS TAB))
```

so it should delete only the records that aren't contained in the two SELECT that you need

Comment: This requires me to give it an user id. So it will keep the required number of rows only for this user. The others may get removed.